# Collecting object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maps

I'm newbie and got a problem while collecting objects in rails.
I have 3 models:
A `has_many B (B belongs_to A)`
B `has_many C (c belongs_to B)`
When i got A, how can I collect all C from A, like this:
`A.Bs.Cs` 
Help me please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kinda easy, Rails supports totally!

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs # has many B
  # The point here
  has_many :cs, through: :bs # has many C through B
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cs
  belongs_to :a
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c
end
```

For example, the query will be

```
A.find(1).cs
```

Btw, you should modify your question with more descriptive info, `A, B, C` is kind of confusing!

Comment: got it, thank you very much!